# Grey hair on a 14 month old baby

Tags: toddler, infant, hair

My son is only 14 months old, but we have recently noticed that he has a white hair on his head. Should we worry?

Comment: Close: Too medical. You should see a doctor for straight health concerns.

Comment: @bobobobo: hmm, I'd say it would be too medical _if it is a medical condition._ If it's a normal phenomenon (that I simply haven't heard of before) then it would be valuable to learn that here. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: I have strokes of white hair at the back of my head while the rest of my hair is pure and very black. Im 13 as of the moment and mom said I had it since I started growing hair. It still weirds me out until now, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the phrasing could be better, @monsto is right. Hair color changes naturally for a large number of reasons. It's not uncommon for infants' and young children's hair color to completely change naturally, nor are patches of off-color hair unheard of (my husband also has a patch of lighter hair on his head).

Why is that? Because there are a ton of factors that control hair color, including (but by no means limited to): genes, levels of melanin (the pigment that determines color and darkness of our skin, hair, and eyes) produced, chemical exposure (swimming a lot in a pool can lighten the hair due to the chlorine, for example), and sun exposure. Not only do/can these factors affect the overall color of your hair, but also the *individual hairs*.

You've probably actually seen people who have multiple colors of hair, naturally, but the color differences are more subtle that you don't realize it. Many people with the lighter shades of brown may also have blonde or red "highlights". This is the same effect.

If it still bothers you, and/or more appear, though, it doesn't hurt to bring it up to your child's doctor at his next checkup.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @Shauna! This is a great community. We will get him checked at this next appointment with the health visitor.

Answer (score 3):

My son's hair is literally two different colors: red and blond.  My hair is also literally two different colors:  very blond and black.  Variation in hair color is perfectly normal.  I had a friend in elementary school who had some grey hair (nothing huge...just a small patch).  If you only see one or a few, I wouldn't worry too much about it, but if you notice lots of it or other alarming symptoms, then I would certainly have him evaluated by a pediatrician.

Answer (score 3):

My great uncle had a stripe of white hair, offcenter on his skull. it was about where men would normally part their hair. Trick is that me and my family are black. so here's a guy in the 1930s with a 'fro and a 1 inch wide skunk stripe down the corner of his head. had it till the day he went all grey.

In other words, I think it's just a white hair. Feed your child, change his butt, make him laff, forget about the white hair.

I think the web has made hyper-hypochondriac's out of all of us. There's an abundance of information and opinion on just about any subject you can think of. the positive opinions are matter of fact and the negative ones are ridiculously passionate. So sometimes I think the internet was just a big mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't.

A little odd, sure.  Just the one?  How long has it been there?

I'd keep an eye out for others.  Maybe its just a weird fluke hair follicle.

Answer (score 0):

My Son has had white or grey hair in his coal black hair since he was three. He is now twenty and still has salt and pepper hair. My Aunt said we have a recessive gene. She said we are prone to have an albino child in our genetics. If that if how you phrase that. 
Other than that he is handsome blue eyed  tall and everything a young man his age should be.